# Paperclip Error: model missing required attr_accessor for 'avatar_file_name'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I then want to use Paperclip to have photos for each Listing. I added the appropriate code to the listings show.html.erb, the listing.rb model, the listings_controller.rb and the _form.html.erb partial.

When I try uploading an image for the Listing I get this error:

```
Paperclip::Error in ListingsController#update
Listing model missing required attr_accessor for 'avatar_file_name'
```

Line 44 of listings_controller:

```
def update
 respond_to do |format|
  if @listing.update(listing_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @listing, notice: 'Listing was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
```

A few things to try: namely adding some code to the listing.rb model to make the acceptable images for the :avatar more robust. Here is what several stackoverflow posts mentioned adding to the listing.rb model:

```
validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => %w(image/jpeg image/jpg image/png)
```

Unfortunately I still get the same error when I attach an image. When I don't attach an image my default image is loaded fine and the listing is created properly.

My Listing model:

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "150x", :thumb => "100x100>" },   :default_url => "default.jpg"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => %w(image/jpeg image/jpg image/png) 
end
```

My _form.html.erb partial:

```
<%= form_for @listing, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <% if @listing.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@listing.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this listing from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @listing.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :company %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :company, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :email %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :phone %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :phone, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :avatar %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :avatar, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My listings_controller.rb controller:

```
 def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @listing.update(listing_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @listing, notice: 'Listing was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
...
def listing_params
   params.require(:listing).permit(:name, :company, :email, :phone, :avatar)
end
```

And my schema.rb file

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140329174335) do

  create_table "listings", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "company"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "phone"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

EDIT: Adding console output after running $rails generate paperclip listing avatar

(I need 10 reputation points to put in post so you have to settle for link https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYxWh.png)

Comment: Did you include :avatar as an allowed parameter in `listing_params`?

Comment: This should be his problem indeed. Within def listing_params you should have the following at the very least: params.require(:listing).permit(:avatar, :avatar_file_name)

Comment: @rails4guides.com, actually you should not need `:avatar_file_name` in the params, just `:avatar` should be enough as Paperclip handles it's own attributes itself. Or put it another way, I've not needed to specify it in my apps.

Comment: You should think so. However, I do remember having seen a github issue where it actually seemed necessary.

Comment: I did add :avatar in the listing_params in the listings_controller. I also tried :avatar_file_name just for good measure and still have the same error.

Comment: @JJThaeler I think you forgot to create the corresponding fields of `avatar` in `listings` table.

Comment: Did you remember to create the `avatar` column in the `listings` table?

Comment: When I generated Paperclip I included the Avatar field. From the Paperclip Git page (https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) I followed this (under Migrations section) for my migration: "Or you can use migration generator: rails generate paperclip user avatar"

Comment: @JJThaeler Why are you running `rails generate paperclip user avatar` ? It should not be on `user` as you want to use it on `listing`. See my updated answer.

Comment: @kirti I was just copy pasting what the Git page for Paperclip said. I used "rails generate paperclip listing avatar"

Answer (score 29):

I suppose you forgot to create the corresponding fields for `avatar` in `listings` table.

I would suggest you to generate a migration to add `avatar` to `listings` table as below:

```
rails generate paperclip listing avatar
```

Then run `rake db:migrate`

### UPDATE

As per your comments and EDIT, you have a migration file to add `avatar` to `listings` table which you created by running `rails generate paperclip user avatar` but unfortunately for some reason its not going through i.e., there are no `avatar specific fields("avatar_file_name", "avatar_content_type", "avatar_file_size" and "avatar_updated_at")` in `listings` table as per your `db/schema.rb`. This is a very strange behavior.

I would suggest you to follow the below mentioned steps in order:

**Destroy** the existing migration, if any:

```
rails destroy paperclip listing avatar
```

**Generate** a new migration:

```
rails generate paperclip listing avatar
```

**Run**

```
rake db:migrate
```

### UPDATE 2

I hope you did not down voted me (but someone did), so I would like to bring it to notice that it is an ongoing issue with Paperclip and I did suggest a solution in my comments (Mar 31) as below:

> I want you to try as gem 'paperclip', :git =>
>   "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git" in Gemfile and then bundle
>   install. Let me know when you finish

Apparently it wasn't noticed by you or someone who down voted me today.
Also, you said `No errors as far as I can tell, image here:` [i.imgur.com/c8KGTa3.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYxWh.png) BUT if you look at the output **there is an error stating clearly:**

> migration_file_name': protected methodmigration_file_name' called for
>   PaperclipGenerator:0x007fb3c6494c20 (NoMethodError)

Comment: I did do this - see above comment.

Comment: BUT did you run the migration? Check fields of `listings` table in the `db/schema.rb` file. It should have 4 fields named "avatar_file_name", "avatar_content_type", "avatar_file_size" and "avatar_updated_at". If they are not present then you didn't run the migration.

Comment: Yep, ran rake several times. Above I've added my schema.rb file.

Comment: Clearly you don't have the paperclip specific fields. See my updated answer to resolve the issue.

Comment: @JJThaeler Yes, see the updated answer.. :) It is much clear.

Comment: @JJThaeler your schema does not have fields for avtar related attributes. You should add a new migration to alter listings table and add those attributes. Use add_attachment :users, :avatar in that migration file.

Comment: @KirtiThorat why are you destroying existing and regenerating paperclip files for listing? A simple new migration file to alter listings table would do the needful.

Comment: @AlokAnand See my UPDATE section as to why I suggested to destroy existing migration.

Comment: @KirtiThorat that's ok, but I still say it is not needed and I suspect avatar attributes are there but in users table as he ran rails generator for paperclip avatar by pointing user model class.

Comment: @AlokAnand +1 Good Catch. It should not be on `user` as OP wants to use it on `listing`.

Comment: I have followed these exact instructions and my schema file does not have any avatar content in the listings table

Comment: @JJThaeler Thanks for clarifying. What output do you get when you run `rails generate paperclip listing avatar` and `rake db:migrate`. It would be helpful if you could share that.

Comment: Ohh.. Now I get it. Source Paperclip gem from Github. Update  the Gemfile for Paperclip gem with  `gem 'paperclip', :git => "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"` and run `bundle install` and try again.

Comment: @kirti Yep I did that too following this (https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1495) recommendation. I've posted this as an issue on Paperclip's Git page.

Comment: I want you to try as `gem 'paperclip', :git => "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"` in Gemfile and then `bundle install`. Let me know when you finish.

Comment: @JJThaeler Please read my UPDATE 2. I hope you didn't down vote me.

Comment: @KirtiThorat no it's some other issue with Paperclip. They responded and I've done everything listed and still no luck. I will need to reboot everything most likely and try again.

Comment: @KirtiThorat Thanks for the answer.  Forgetting the migration was exactly my issue (upvoted to get you out of the negatives...).

Comment: I had the similar issue . But my problem was i generated paper clip using a name called attachment and mistakenly used name avatar in my controller and model ```rails g paperclip document attachment```

Answer (score 4):

From the error message, file_name is not available in the model to which you're trying to save. I had a similar problem and realized I forgot to run the Paperclip migration:

`rails generate paperclip [Model Name] [Attachment]`  (e.g., `rails g paperclip Images image`)

If that doesn't work, since the issue it's having is column "file_name", try adding that to the model (e.g. `rails g migration addFilenameToImages file_name:string`)

This worked for me, so hopefully it helps some of you too!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that in paperclip_database:migration you use plural for the new table name and in the paperclip generator you use singular:

```
rails g paperclip_database:migration cms_article_category cms_article_category_images
rails g paperclip cms_article_category cms_article_category_image
```

And check the resulting column names in your database
 In your example the column in the avatar table should be called avatar_file_name