# Paperclip and Dropbox Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, paperclip, dropbox

Heroku is a whinny little girl.
I was uploading images to the public folder , but heroku doesn´t like it, So the new deal was uploading to s3, But I don´t have a credit card. Sooo I am using paperclip-dropbox to upload images to dropbox and then display them. I made an account  and an App. But with all the code and tutorials, there´s nothing I have to do with:

```
 Paperclip::Error in GaleriaController#create
 Galerium model missing required attr_accessor for 'foto_file_name'


 app/controllers/galeria_controller.rb:64:in `new'
 app/controllers/galeria_controller.rb:64:in `create'
```

It´s in Spanish. "foto" is the image and "galeria" is the database.

**migrate/123491234691274_create_galeria.rb**

```
class CreateGaleria < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
   create_table :galeria do |t|
     t.string :titulo
     t.string :descripcion
     t.string :extension

     t.timestamps
   end

  add_attachment :galeria, :foto
 end
end
```

**app/models/galerium.rb**

```
class Galerium < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :descripcion, :titulo , :foto 
 has_attached_file :foto ,
   :storage => :dropbox,
   :dropbox_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/dropbox_config.yml",
   :styles => {},  
   :dropbox_options => {       
   :path => proc { |style| "#{Rails.env}/#{style}/#{id}_#{picture.original_filename}"},            :unique_filename => true 
    }
 def self.search(query)
   where("titulo like ?", "%#{query}%") 
 end
end
```

**app/controllers/galeria_controller.rb**

```
 $paginate = true
 class GaleriaController < ApplicationController
 #Index de galeria
   def index
     if params[:search]
       @fotos = Galerium.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
       $paginate = false
       @search_params = params[:search]
      else
       @fotos = Galerium.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 8).find(:all, :order => "id desc")
       $paginate  = true
     end  

     respond_to do |format|
       format.html # index.html.erb
       format.json { render json: @fotos } #no sirve
     end
   end

   # GET /galeria/1
   # GET /galeria/1.json
   def show

     @galerium = Galerium.find(params[:id])

     respond_to do |format|
       format.html # show.html.erb
       format.json { render json: @galerium }
     end
   end

   # GET /galeria/new
   # GET /galeria/new.json
   def new

       @galerium = Galerium.new

       respond_to do |format|
         format.html # new.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @galerium }
       end   
   end

   # GET /galeria/1/edit
   def edit    

       @galerium = Galerium.find(params[:id])
   end

   # POST /galeria
   # POST /galeria.json
   def create

      @galerium = Galerium.new(params[:galerium])

       respond_to do |format|
        if @galerium.save
           format.html { redirect_to @galerium, notice: 'Galerium was successfully created.' }
           format.json { render json: @galerium, status: :created, location: @galerium }
         else
           format.html { render action: "new" }
           format.json { render json: @galerium.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end  
   end

   # PUT /galeria/1
   # PUT /galeria/1.json
   def update
      @galerium = Galerium.find(params[:id])

      respond_to do |format|
        if @galerium.update_attributes(params[:galerium])
          format.html { redirect_to @galerium, notice: 'Galerium was successfully updated.' }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        else
          format.html { render action: "edit" }
           format.json { render json: @galerium.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end 
   end

   # DELETE /galeria/1
   # DELETE /galeria/1.json
   def destroy
      @galerium = Galerium.find(params[:id])
      @galerium.destroy

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to galeria_url }
        format.json { head :no_content }
       end
     end

   end
   def galeria_params
     params.require(:galeria).permit(:titulo, :descripcion, :foto)
   end
 end
```

Even I had run

```
  rake db:migrate
```

and

```
 rake db:reset
```

Comment: You probably got the downvote for the phrase `heroku is a whiny little girl` LOL. Although it's a classic comment, you got to remember the sheer effort that went into making it *and* that it's mostly free, or very low cost ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this error before - I originally presumed it was caused by a lack of the `paperclip` columns in your db. However, according to [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580592/model-missing-required-attr-accessor-for-photo-file-name-when-uploading-with-p) [sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22746393/paperclip-error-model-missing-required-attr-accessor-for-avatar-file-name), this is not the case.

The error seems to be a common issue, which has several fixes:

--

**`heroku run rake db:migrate`**

Seems the most common cause of the issue is your `heroku` db is not updated with the columns required. You've tried running the migrations locally, but not in production

If you're using `Herouk toolbelt,` you can use `heroku run rake db:migrate` to trigger the command on your heroku instance

--

**`strong params`**

Rails 4 makes a big point of using `strong params`. Apart from the answer above, you need to also ensure you're using your code properly:

```
#app/controllers/galeria_controller.rb
def create
   @galeria = Galeria.new galeria_params
end

private

def galeria_params
    params.require(:galaria).permit(:galeria, :params, :foto)
end
```

--

[**`paperclip-dropbox`**](https://github.com/janko-m/paperclip-dropbox)

The other thing you may need to consider is the use of the `paperclip-dropbox` gem. This is an additive to the standard `paperclip` gem, which facilitates interaction between your app and `dropbox`

Are you using this gem?