# RoR Undefined Method 'attr_accessor'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip, erb

I am building a blog that allows me to post pictures, and when a new post w/ a picture comes up, I get an error saying "require attr_accessor for 'image_file_name'". So I put my "attr_accessor :image" in there and I get an "undefined method error 'attr_accessor'".
https://github.com/BBaughn1/savagelysaving <-- the github if you need it

```
def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

This is before the error,

```
def create
    attr_accessor :image
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

and this is after the error.
And, I got this error earlier but fixed it with this:

```
def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    attr_accessor :image
    if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :body, :image))
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

putting "attr_accessor :image" before the "@post = Post.new(post_params)" will give me the same error saying that I require "attr_accessor"

Comment: wasn't what I was looking for but thanks

Comment: says it must by "CONSTANT"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Paperclip Error: model missing required attr\_accessor for 'avatar\_file\_name'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22746393/paperclip-error-model-missing-required-attr-accessor-for-avatar-file-name)

Comment: That duplicate made it worse. I took what I read (Destroy the existing migration, if any:

rails destroy paperclip listing avatar, then I needed to  
generate a new migration:

rails generate paperclip listing avatar, and finaly

rake db:migrate) and I ended up getting an error saying "rake aborted!"....

Comment: and for every "avatar," I did "image"

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is simply a naming mismatch. [Your schema](https://github.com/BBaughn1/savagelysaving/blob/master/db/schema.rb) shows you have the attributes avatar_file_name, avatar_content_type, avatar_file_size, and avatar_updated_at. But in [your model](https://github.com/BBaughn1/savagelysaving/blob/master/app/models/post.rb), you have `has_attached_file :image`. These two items [should match up](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#models). it sounds like you probably want `has_attached_file :avatar`, instead. You will need to replace other relevant occurrences of "image" with "avatar" in your views and controllers, as well. You also should remove the `attr_accessor :image` from your model. Your error indicates that the required fields do not exist in the database, for the structure you have defined.

Comment: "Avatar" or "image", it doesn't matter. You could call it "turkey_leg" if you really wanted, but you need to be consistent.